# Pasting file not work from clipboard on react

Tags: reactjs, clipboarddata

I want to implement image upload by pasting from the clipboard.

so, I tried that get a file object from onPaste

```
const handlePaste = (e)=>{
   console.log(e.clipboardData);
}
<input onPaste={(e)=>handlePaste(e)} />
```

In console.log I don't get any data. Here is the SC for reference.

[image: Screeenshot]

How to tackle this? Is there any alternative for this so that we could get the image data and display the image using blob ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onPasteCapture`

```
<input onPasteCapture={(e) => {
    console.log(e.clipboardData.files)
}} />
```